# Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process 'sampleapp'

Tags: django, ubuntu, apache2

I tried to install django in ubuntu server and i had 503 error in error.log
my apache2.conf is:

```
<VirtualHost x.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080>
ServerAlias www.samplesite.com
ServerAdmin info@samplesite.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/sampleapp/
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/sampleapp/cgi-bin/
Alias /vstats/ /var/www/sampleapp/stats/
Alias /error/ /var/www/sampleapp/document_error
#SuexecUserGroup admin admin
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domains/sampleapp.ir.bytes bytes
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domains/sampleapp.ir.log combined
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/domains/sampleapp.ir.error.log
WSGIProcessGroup sampleapp
WSGIScriptAlias /sampleapp /var/www/sampleapp/sampleapp/wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess sampleapp python-path=/var/www/sampleapp:/var/www    /sampleapp/envme/lib/python3.4/site-packages
<Directory /var/www/sampleapp/static/>
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/sampleapp/media/>
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/sampleapp/sampleapp/>
<Files wsgi.py>
require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/sampleapp/>
AllowOverride All
    Options +Includes +Indexes +ExecCGI

   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and i have this error in my error.log:

```
(13)Permission denied: [client x.xxx.xx.xxx:59504] mod_wsgi (pid=26905): Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process 'sampleapp' on '/var/run/apache2/wsgi.26899.0.1.sock' as user with uid=1005.
```

I lost 2 days trying to solve it,

Answer (score 3):

You can refer this url,

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationIssues#Location_Of_UNIX_Sockets

Adding this,

```
WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi
```

will solve the error. The solution is to change where the socket files are kept to a location where Apache user can read them.

Comment: can u explain what can i do in my problem, and where i should add WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi? i cant see "http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationIssues#Location_Of_UNIX_Sockets"

Comment: `WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi`, Kindly to add above the Virtual host blog at the global scope in apache configuration, and restart the services,.

Comment: i add WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi before virtualhost and but have that error